# How to include a Gradle distribution in the project to be used for the wrapper

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I want to include a specific version of Gradle in the project folder so that when I use the Gradle wrapper it doesn't download it from the remote repository.

I downloaded the version of Gradle I need (`gradle-4.0-bin.zip`) and I put that zip fine inside of `gradle/wrapper/` folder of the project (created with the `gradle wrapper` command).
Then I edited the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in this way:

```
distributionUrl=file:///Users/pathj/to/the/project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-4.0-bin.zip
```

But when I run the first command, such as `gradle task` it returns:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project '03-gradle-wrapper-local'.
>
>   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/myself/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.0-bin/3p92xsbhik5vmig8i90n16yxc/gradle-4.0/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-4.0.jar
>   >     (No such file or directory)

How do I tell Gradle to get the zip file from the current project folder, with a relative path, instead of downloading it, and to use that zip file to create a wrapper to be used in my builds?

Comment: Why? Just why? You would then have to store this big zip file in your git repo, and force every developer to download it from the git repo (along with every previous version you stored), instead of using their own local copy.

Comment: Hello JB Nizet. Well, there is no why. I'm just going through the Gradle documentation and do some experiments. Since the documentation says: "If you don’t want any download to happen when your project is built via gradlew, simply add the Gradle distribution zip to your version control at the location specified by your Wrapper configuration." I wanted to try this. If it is in the documentation probably it has some practical example of usage :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from storing gradle wrapper locally make sense or not it is possible. I assume that `gradle-4.0-rc-3-bin` distro is used.

Here is the project structure:

```
.
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-4.0-rc-3-bin.zip
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
└── gradlew.bat
```

And here the content of `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=PROJECT
distributionPath=gradle
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=gradle-4.0-rc-3-bin.zip
```

Since wrapper files will be downloaded to the project dir adding `gradle/gradle-4.0-rc-3-bin` to SCM ignore file is recommended.

Demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/47218397).

Comment: From the documentation: "If you don’t want any download to happen when your project is built via gradlew, simply add the Gradle distribution zip to your version control at the location specified by your Wrapper configuration." so I guess that including the distribution under SCM is something that has some usefulness.

Comment: @acejazz, I don't judge it. I was just referring to what JB Nizet's comment.

Comment: oh ok. I got it wrong. :)
I tried to use your solution but it doesn't work though,

Comment: @acejazz actually it works well. Copy the whole folder and run `./gradlew`. What errors do you get?

Comment: The gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionBase=PROJECT
distributionPath=gradle
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=gradle-4.0-bin.zip

The error is this one:
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'To finish 03-gradle-wrapper-local'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/myself/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.0-bin/3p92xsbhik5vmig8i90n16yxc/gradle-4.0/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-4.0.jar (No such file or directory)

Comment: Your version actually works.
I'll try to see the differences between yours and mine.
Thanks a lot in the meantime!

Comment: @acejazz, sure. Let me know if you worked it out finally.

Comment: it worked! The problem was that in the script I was calling `gradle wrapper` before actually calling `./gradlew` and therefore the properties file was overriden. Thank you! P.S. Is there a way to configure the properties file for this purpose from the build script?

Comment: Cool. To be honest I don't know.